# How to solve login with token and don't want to move to the home page

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Permissions ask, I want to save the token via sharedpreferences but when I login the app doesn't want to go to the home page, but when I refresh the token, it is saved and goes straight to the home page.
is there something wrong in writing my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method (like "`checkIfUserExist()`" call in `initState`) to check if the user is already login to your app and then accordingly they will go to the next screen.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    checkIfUserExist();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> checkIfUserExist() async {
    final SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String userToken = _prefs.getString(Constant.token) ?? '';
    if (userToken != '') {
        // navigation to Home screen
    } else {
        // navigation to Signup screen
    }
  }
```